# Need some help understanding this calculation of distance from a point to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have som trouble understanding this algorithm for finding the minimum distance from a  point to a line in a 2-dimensional space.

Given a line between two points p1(x1, y1) and p2(x2, y2), find the minimum distance from p3(x, y).

Ive tried the following algorithm for finding this:

1. I find direction vector **v** of p1 and p2.
2. I find the unit vector **u** (normalized direction vector) of v
3. I compute the dot product of p1 and u
4. I compute the dot product of p3 and u
5. Then I compute the difference **d** between these two dot products by substracting the first from the second

This is where I get a little lost:

5. I take **e1** = p1.x + d * u.x
6. I take **e2** = p1.y + d * u.y
7. I substract e1 from p.x and e2 from p.y (this will be **d1** and **d2**)

Then finally I just find the magnitude of d1 and d2.

The process works, but I am more interested in knowing why it works. I am kinda bad at math, but I want to understand what exactly is happening here. Any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: You didn't say what `p` is.

Comment: In step 4 what is p? In general, if u is a unit vector, then the dot product of p with u is the component of p in the direction of u.

Comment: p is p3, my bad. Edited the main post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance of a point $P$ from a line $L$... Write $N$  for the line through $P$ perpendicular to the line $L$. Parametrize $N$:
$$  {\bf x}(t)=  \pmatrix {x(t)\\ y(t)} = P + t {\bf n},$$
where $\bf n$ is a vector of length one (in the direction of $N$). Now,  ${\bf x}(0) = P$. Therefore, since $\bf n$ is of length one (we are walking away from $P$ at speed one), the distance of $P$ from $L$ is, up to sign, equal to the $t$ such that ${\bf x}(t)$ ALSO belongs to $L$ (how long it takes us to reach $L$ from $P$).

Your algorithm (I haven't checked that it's right!) should basically boil down to  solving for $t$.
The line $L$ is the line perpendicular to $\bf n$ through $P_1$, and therefore has equation $$ {\bf n}\cdot ( {\bf x}- P_1)=0,$$
for any ${\bf x} =(x,y)$ on the line $L$.

So substituting, we can solve for $t$:
$${\bf n} \cdot (P+ t{\bf n} - P_1)=0.$$
This reduces to $${\bf n}\cdot(P-P_1) + t{\bf n}\cdot {\bf n} = 0.$$ 
But since ${\bf n}$ has length one, ${\bf n} \cdot {\bf n} =1$.

Therefore, $$ {\bf n}\cdot(P-P_1) + t = 0,$$ and the distance of $P$ to $L$ has to be 
$$ | {\bf n}\cdot(P-P_1)|. $$
Now, ${\bf n}$ is perpendicular to your unit vector ${\bf u}$, so if ${\bf u} = (u_1, u_2)$, then we can take ${\bf n} = (-u_2,u_1)$.

This should match up with your algorithm (up to swapping the roles of $P_1$ and $P_2$, say)... Hope this helps.

EDIT/ADDENDUM... Much more simply! Look at the vector $P-P_1$. We want the length of its projection onto $\bf n$, as this is precisely the distance $d$ of $P$ to the line $L$, i.e., geometrically, $d$ equals (up to sign) $ |P-P_1|\cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between (the segment) $P-P_1$ and $\bf n$. Use dot products: since $\bf n$ has length one,  once again,
$$d=\Big| \, |P-P_1| | {\bf n}| \cos \theta \, \Big| = |  {\bf n}\cdot(P-P_1)|. $$

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** The distance to a line is measured in a direction perpendicular to it; $E=P_1+d\mathbf u$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $P_3$ to $\overline{P_1P_2}$.

[image: distance to line]

$Q_1=(\mathbf u\cdot P_1)\,\mathbf u$ and $Q_3=(\mathbf u\cdot P_3)\,\mathbf u$ are the orthogonal projections of $P_1$ and $P_3$, respectively, onto the vector $\mathbf u$, which is parallel to the line $\mathcal L = \overline{P_1P_2}$. The vector $Q_3-Q_1 = (\vec u\cdot P_3-\vec u\cdot P_1)\,\mathbf u = d\mathbf u$ represents a displacement equal to the distance between $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ parallel to $\mathcal L$. Adding this to $P_1$ results in a point $E$ that’s the orthogonal projection of $P_3$ onto $\mathcal L$, i.e., the foot of the perpendicular from $P_3$. Since the distance to a line is measured in a direction perpendicular to it, the distance between $P_3$ and $\mathcal L$ is therefore $\|P_3-E\|$.

As an alternative way to compute this distance, observe that the absolute value of $$\frac12\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{vmatrix}=\frac12\Delta$$ is equal to the area of $\triangle{P_1P_2P_3}$. (The sign indicates the direction in which the vertices are traversed.) Since the area of a triangle is also given by the formula $\frac12bh$, if we take $P_1P_2$ as the base, then $h$ is the length of the altitude to $P_3$, which is exactly the distance to the line that we’re trying to compute. Therefore, $$\|P_3-E\|={|\Delta|\over\|P_2-P_1\|}.$$ I believe the this is a bit more efficient than the algorithm you’re using: It has the same number of operations as steps 1-5 of that algorithm, plus an absolute value instead of all of the other things that go on in the later steps.